# How to clear previous Activity on Android without start new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I want to clear previous activity but without start new activity on android.

Usually I use this code when change with cleaning

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

but how if I don't want to change activities? maybe someone can help me..

Comment: Don't use splash activity, that is not the recommended way. You can customise the theme for splash activity. In this way you no need to clear the previous activity which is SplashActivity in your case. Let me know if you need code for that.

Comment: @Parmesh sounds good idea. may I see what the code looks like? so I can learn and try:)

Comment: I have provided the solution for my approach, you can find the full code in my GitHub repository(links are provided in solution). Let me know if you still need any further help.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear previous `Activity`?

Comment: SplashActivity.this.finish(); try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1:Create a drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" />
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/img_splash" />
</item>
```

Code link: [splash_theme_bg.xml](https://github.com/CrazyCommunity/community-android-app/blob/onboarding-flow/app/src/main/res/drawable/splash_theme_bg.xml)

Step2: Create Style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_theme_bg</item>
</style>
```

Code link: [styles.xml](https://github.com/CrazyCommunity/community-android-app/blob/onboarding-flow/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml)

Step3: Set style in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Code link: [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/CrazyCommunity/community-android-app/blob/onboarding-flow/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

**Let me know if you still get stuck anywhere.**
Happy Coding!

Comment: Great! thankss bro, i will try it!. I'll ask you again if there's a problem..