# How to display a screen for a few seconds when the app launches?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to display a screen for a few seconds when my app launches but I can't find how to do it in kotlin. I wanted that screen to be the first the user sees, then, after a few seconds, it would go directly to the login screen, can you help me?

Comment: It's called a splash screen , [refer this](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

Comment: Check this answer where you no need to create different activity for splash screen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864375/how-to-clear-previous-activity-on-android-without-start-new-activity/68864767#68864767

Comment: You can use a library like [Lottie](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/README) for that purpose. And on this site (https://lottiefiles.com/)[https://lottiefiles.com/] you can download bunch of animation for your application.

Answer (score 0):

please use handler to add some time delay to launch next functionality (in your case is launch next activity )

```
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          displayData();
        }
    }, 5000);  //5000 is delay time you can change according to you need
```

Comment: Adding delay in the app for every launch is not a good idea, it's better practice to customise theme for splash screen.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new Activity then set it as your starting activity like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, in your `SplashScreenActivity`, handle the delay like this:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}, 3000)  // 3 seconds
```

Comment: This is also not a good practice to block main thread for few seconds. This will not give good user experience as user will wait for given seconds every time they launch app.